# Convert string to array of uint8_t

Tags: java, c, arduino

For my project I need to read some single line text from a SD card, then get the hex or dec value of each character within the string and group those values in an array.

There are no whitespaces in the text and the lines end with \n

I'm using this code to read all the content into a single string!

```
            String line = "";

            while (dataFile.available() != 0) 
            {   
              line = dataFile.readStringUntil('\n');    
              if (line == "") 
                break;  
            }
```

For later use I need to calculate the hex values of each character, this code should iterate over the String and group it in an array.

```
            int lineSize = line.length();

            uint8_t data[lineSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; i++)
            {
              data[i] = line.charAt(i);                 
            }
```

I really don't know wether this works or not, but I doubt that I will get the actual hex values...

The values are somewhere but I really don't know how to access them!

The result should look like this:

```
uint8_t data[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry if confused you, my question is how to convert a given string in an array of characters and get the hex value for each characters.

Comment: Are you working in C++? There's no `String` in C.

Comment: so you are reading a line, and each character in the line must be converted to hex and then stored in an array called data?

Comment: What do you consider to be "*hex value of a character*"? `'A' == 65 == 0x41` all three are integers using 8(7)bits.

Comment: Fiddling Bits as the tags says I'm in the Arduino environment and I'm happily using Strings

Comment: alk, 0x41 is hex code!?

Comment: @user3125138 What alk is saying is that internally, everything is binary.  Is doesn't matter if you consider it decimal, hexadecimal, or whatnot.

Comment: So, what language do you want all this in:  C, C++, Java,...?  I ask because your post in tagged C, but it looks like you are writing in Java or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Think of Hexadecimal***  as just another format to display any data type (uint8_t, or char or int...) stored in memory.  In memory, its all binary, or hexadecimal.  Just depends on how you want to look at it.

For example:  the following statements:

```
long int    A = 34;
uint8_t     B = 34;
char        C = 34;
int         D = 34;

printf("0x%02x\n", 'A'); // surrounded with '' gives ASCII value of 65, then displayed in Hex
printf("0x%02x\n", A);
printf("0x%02x\n", B);
printf("0x%02x\n", C);
printf("0x%02x\n", D);
```

Results in:
[image]

Breaking any string into its fundamental elements, (char, or uint8_t) and printing them as shown above will yield similar results for you.

***Edit***:
For this input file (call it in.txt, in the executable directory):

```
lkjahldfkjghlskjhlskjhlakdjgglsjkahlkj4hl5k6jh67=83kjhlkjshdf8f7s698s7dfgbslfkjbg
```

***And using this code:***

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[]=".\\in.txt";
    uint8_t c;
    int length=0, i=0;
    uint8_t *array;

    //Get number of entries in file:
    fp=fopen(filename, "r");
    c= fgetc(fp);
    while(c<255)
    {
        length++;   
        c= fgetc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    //give array sufficient space
    array = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*length);

    fp=fopen(filename, "r");

    //read file into array, and display as hexadecimal
    c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c<255)
    {
        array[i++]= c;
        printf("0x%02x\n", c);
        c = fgetc(fp);  
    }
    fclose(fp);
        getchar();//stop execution to view files (hit any key to exit)
        return 0
}
```

***You should see*** this output:  (only first 20 or so values shown...)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C/C++ are already arrays (even when abstracted by a higher level class like `std::string`). The array elements are the character values of each character. Are you sure you can't just grab the string's .[c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)() (or .[data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)()) and use that, possibly with a cast?

Comment: actually I really need those HEX values, the application which takes the value only accepts this form

Comment: @user3125138 See **alk**'s comment on your post. What you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. When numbers are stored in numeric variables there's no difference between "hex" or "decimal" or anything, they're just numbers. Do you actually mean this application is expecting a **string** containing a hexadecimal **representation** of the character's value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by getting the hex code you mean getting the hex representation of those characters, you can do this -

```
const String hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";
char hex[2] = "";

hex[0] = hexDigits[ (int)line.at(i) / 16 ];
hex[1] = hexDigits[ (int)line.at(i) % 16 ];
```

For example, if `line.at(i) = A`, then `hex` will be `"41"`.

Comment: Post tagged as C, not, ... whatever that is. (java?)